# MIB_IPFORWARDROW metric(s) vs. ROUTE's

Tags: winapi, routes, metric, windows-networking, platform-sdk

In the Windows command line, the 'ROUTE PRINT' command yields a tabular list of entries, with a single column labeled '**Metric**'.

In the Windows Platform SDK, you can fetch the same values (more or less) via the API, through the structure [MIB_IPFORWARDROW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366850%28VS.85%29.aspx). I can correlate most of the fields in MIB_IPFORWARDROW to the one's in ROUTE PRINT's but when it comes to Metrics, MIB_IPFORWARDROW has 5 (five!) metric fields. Which one of them is ROUTE PRINT's Metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops... I missed that part in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366850%28VS.85%29.aspx) that says:

> A number of members of the
>   MIB_IPFORWARDROW structure are not
>   currently used by IPv4 routing. These
>   members include dwForwardPolicy,
>   dwForwardNextHopAS, dwForwardMetric2,
>   dwForwardMetric3, dwForwardMetric4,
>   and dwForwardMetric5.

So, answering myself: In IPv4, ROUTE PRINT's Metric is dwForwardMetric1 in MIB_IPFORWARDROW.